# Fully automate a Let's Encrypt certificate request when adding a new domain in DirectAdmin

Tags: php, curl, lets-encrypt, directadmin

I am looking for a way to automate the proces of creating a new Let's Encrypt certificate upon adding a new domain in Direct Admin. Currently I am making a script that will add multiple domain names to DirectAdmin under the same user, which has already succeeded. Now I am trying to add a Let's Encrypt certificate with it.

I don't mind if it is done on the server itself or by any API that is available.

I do have fully access to the server, and I have already installed Let's Encrypt on the server.

Here are the server specs:

```
Processor Name = Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1220 v3 @ 3.10GHz<br>
Vendor ID = GenuineIntel<br>
Processor Speed (MHz) = 3101.000<br>
Processor Name = Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1220 v3 @ 3.10GHz<br>
Vendor ID = GenuineIntel<br>
Processor Speed (MHz) = 800.000<br>
Processor Name = Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1220 v3 @ 3.10GHz<br>
Vendor ID = GenuineIntel<br>
Processor Speed (MHz) = 3101.000<br>
Processor Name = Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1220 v3 @ 3.10GHz<br>
Vendor ID = GenuineIntel<br>
Processor Speed (MHz) = 3101.000<br>
<br>
Apache 2.4.39 = Running<br>
DirectAdmin 1.55.0 = Running<br>
Exim 4.84 = Running<br>
MySQL 5.5.31 = Running<br>
Named 9.8.2rc1 = Running<br>
ProFTPd 1.3.6 = Running<br>
sshd = Running<br>
dovecot 2.3.6 (7eab80676) = Running<br>
Php 7.3.5 = Installed<br>
Php 7.2.18 = Installed (php2)<br>
```

I have tried to find an option to use the API which I do also use to add the domains to DirectAdmin, sadly enough I was not able to find a solution.

Also I have tried to take a look at shell scripts, which I did not fully understand because I have seen people talk about that.

No code has been made yet

I hope to get an API, explenation or links on how to be able to generate Let's Encrypt SSL certificates through an API or just add a certificate with every domain that is being added under a specific user.

Comment: Just follow this link : https://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=629
and you can also read this one : https://support.yourwebhoster.eu/en-us/article/44-how-to-enable-let-s-encrypt-in-directadmin
then all of your clients can go to `SSL` and install it for themselves by 2 click.